# How can I import a mysql dump?

Tags: database, mysql

I have created a mysql dump for only one table in my database. The command I used to create the dump was  `mysqldump -uroot -p database_name table_name > backup.sql`. Now, when I am trying to import the data into my machine using the command "`mysql -uroot -p database_name table_name < backup.sql`" I am not getting anything.

I only get text on command line which explains me how to use mysql command. Is there anything i am missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `table_name`.

```
mysql -uroot -p database_name < backup.sql
```

Comment: Do you know the root password?

Comment: and reember that the host is included in the grants - root isn't uber everywhere unless the server is set up that way

Answer (score 0):

Does the schema exist on your server? If you didn't used the --databases option, I don't think it adds the `create database database_name` and `use database_name`. You might have to execute these steps manually from the command line client.

Comment: Schema does exist on my server