# How to import mysql dump to SQLyog

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I have few sql dump files like the tables taken from other db. Now i want to update the tables into my server using the sqlyog. So can anyone help me out in importing .sql files into the SQLyog ???
Thank u in advance

Comment: Why use SQLYog, mysqldump is already an available command with server.  e.g. mysqldump --opt --user=username --password database > dumbfile.sql

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390203/how-can-i-import-a-mysql-dump

Answer (score 8):

In SQLyog there is an option - `Tools -> Execute SQL script`. You can use this to run SQL scripts.

Answer (score 4):

In order to make it clear please refer the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Why use SQLYog, mysqldump is already an available command with server.

```
mysqldump --opt --user=username --password database > dumbfile.sql
```

where dumbfile will be your sql file.

[MYSQLDump command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) I have used it a lot to get databases export and is highly reliable.

And mysql command to import the same:

```
mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```

Comment: @Himanshu Bhardwaj mysqldump makes backup, he needs to run SQL files.

Comment: Yep @Devart is correct, here is correct command: mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql

Answer (score 2):

In SQLyog there is an option - `Tools -> Execute SQL script`. If there are some Errors it will give you a pop up, then click on the `"Open Error File button"`, it will give you error in the sql file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can open your SQL file in Query window, and just run it in SQLYog. Have a look at this documentation page - [Executing SQL Queries](https://www.webyog.com/webyog/sqlyogDocs).

Also, you can use [mysql — The MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html), or [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (free express edition) to execute SQL files against the MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLyog v7.14, run DB -> Restore from SQL Dump..., or just press Ctrl+Shift+Q.